# gridlayouts attribute in Android Studio 3.5

Tags: android-studio, attributes, grid-layout, android-studio-3.5

After I drag in the grid layout the attributes are hidden or not there:

[image: screenshot of my problem]

Comment: I see you are new to the site; welcome!  To help get better answers to your question, it's recommended that you paste your code into the formatter instead of having a link to a screenshot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] the question to indicate where you are dragging that causes this to happen, maybe also include the version of Android Studio in the question, not just in the title.